# limitation on Decorator in Querying unPartitioned Tables in BigQuery? (LegacySQL) [dataset.table_name@-16502400000-]

Tags: google-bigquery, decorator

Greetings my fellow stack overflowers

I'm trying to run a query on the past six months from a none-partitioned table , using decorator, translating 191 days to miliseconds - [dataset.table_name@-16502400000-]

Yet the results show me only the past two months

Is there some kind of a limitation on decorators?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure? The limit is actually only 7 days!

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot-syntax) is mentioned:

> time must be within the last 7 days and greater than or equal to the
>   table's creation time.

Taking that in to the account, decorators are limited to the past 7 days.